# PHP 5.4 on RedHat Openshift Online

Tags: php, apache, openshift

I'm trying to explore openshift as a possible service to use for a project or two.
I require PHP 5.4 due to the fact that a dependency I'm using makes use of PHP Traits. 
Obviously the default on offer on Openshift Online is PHP 5.3. I have looked around & learned about Cartridges but for the life of me can't get them to work.

I found this solution which is recommended all over the place : [Sgoettschkes/openshift-php54](https://github.com/Sgoettschkes/openshift-php54), but following the instructions; I keep getting a timeout error informing me that my session has been ended due to it taking too long. (despite the fact that the readme warns one that the process may take up to an hour...)

I can't tell for sure but that particular solution appears to be a V1 cartridge? I've tried to check out V2 cartridges but they keep throwing errors when I try to use them. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. [smerrill/openshift-php-54](https://github.com/smerrill/openshift-php-54)

error examples:
" --2013-08-22 12:07:38-- http://phpbuild-phase2technology.rhcloud.com/php54.tgz Resolving phpbuild-phase2technology.rhcloud.com... failed: Name or service not known. wget: unable to resolve host address `phpbuild-phase2technology.rhcloud.com' "

and

" Invalid cartridge, error downloading from url 'https://github.com/smerrill/openshift-php-54/archive/master.zip' "

(I've tried this using both the rhc application & the web interface)

I have seen that one needs to make use of the cartridge reflector, but that hasn't helped. Is there something I'm not doing? [info here:](https://www.openshift.com/developers/download-cartridges)

Unfortunately every resource I read seems to assume that the reader or viewer knows a lot about the subject beforehand, which I don't. Even watching a video where the speaker skipped concepts because he assumed one already knew this stuff. [Video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaumvCvundY). I feel like I'd have been set up faster if I had gone and gotten myself a VPS, but the idea is to have a set up that requires less management.

My desire would be to get up & running PHP 5.4, Apache & MySql for a start. I won't even throw in the extra php libraries just because I don't want to get confused.

Can anyone help me get things running? As layman as possible would help.

Comment: The quickstart (https://github.com/Sgoettschkes/openshift-php54) is working for me.  The steps I used are:  
|1) rhc app create php54 diy-0.1  
|2) cd php54
|3) git remote add upstream -m master https://github.com/Sgoettschkes/openshift-php54   
|4) git pull -s recursive -X theirs upstream master  
|5) git push

Comment: Then, |6) rhc ssh php54  
|7) unset TMOUT  
|8) nohup $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/misc/install.sh > $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/install.log

Comment: Feel free to post issues to https://github.com/smerrill/openshift-php-54 as it's not working for me either.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll give that a try & report back.

Comment: sorry to take so long to report back; it did in fact work with the steps you described. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @NamDuong can you perhaps expand your comments into an answer which is more readable? an explanation of each step and what 'nohup' does would also be useful ;)

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have forked the repo to make it work for me. Couple of issues i faced was

1. Broken Link of dependency
2. Incorrect mentioned php 5 version, which is fixed in the forked repo.

I have also submitted a pull request [here](https://github.com/Sgoettschkes/openshift-php54/pull/6), meanwhile working code can be accessible from my forked [repo](https://github.com/skohli0302/openshift-php54).

Feel free to submit improvements. happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

[PHP 5.4 is now available on OpenShift Online, see this blog post](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/php-54-web-hosting-is-now-on-openshift).